# Can a joker be played on its own?

Tags: rummikub

I was down to a single tile, a joker, and I wanted to place it next to any set already on the table. However, my opponent said a wild tile must always be played with two other tiles from your hand.
Could I have played the joker in this case?

Answer (score 6):

Your opponent is confused. As you can see in the [rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf):

> The Joker:There are two jokers in the game. They can be used for any
>   tile in a set. A joker used in theopening set scores the value of the
>   tiles it represents. A joker can be retrieved from a set on thetable
>   by a player who can replace it during his turn with a tile of the same
>   numerical value andcolor it represents. The tile used to replace the
>   Joker must come from a player's rack and notfrom the table. In the
>   case of a group of 3, the joker can be replaced by the tile of either
>   of the missing colors. **A joker that has been replaced must be used in
>   the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a
>   new set.** Players cannot retrieve a joker before they have laid their
>   initial set(s). A set containing a joker can have tiles added to it
>   and can be split apart or have tiles removed from it. The joker has a
>   penalty value of 30 points if it remains on a player'srack at the end
>   of a game.

You can play a single joker from your hand. But, **if you replace a joker with another tile, you have to play it with two tiles of your hand.**

So you can play the joker.